# owl-carousel slider is not working. When I load the component in angular 8

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

When I refresh my window then slider is working fine but when I go to another component and after that load same component in which slider then it is not working. When I refresh then again slider is working fine.I have need to this slider because I want to slide one by one slide so it is best but I don't know why it is not working without refresh window. I can load one component to another component but how to refresh component every time when redirect to component of slider.

*Component.html*

```
      <owl-carousel #owlElement  [options]="SlideOptions" [items]="images"
                        [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'sliding', owl-carousel]">

                        <div class="item">
                            <a class="red" href="#">Site1</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a class="red" href="#">Site2</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a class="red" href="#">Site3</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a class="red" href="#">Site4</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a class="red" href="#">Site5</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a class="green" href="#">Site6</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a class="green" href="#">Site7</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a class="green" href="#">Site8</a>
                        </div>
                        
                    </owl-carousel>
```

Component.ts

```
                export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
               @ViewChild('owlElement', {static: true}) owlElement: OwlCarousel;
               constructor() { }

          ngOnInit() {
            this.refreshSlider();
               }
             Images = ['../assets/images/Carousel1.jpeg', '../assets/images/Carousel2.jpeg', 
          '../assets/images/Carousel3.jpeg'];

           SlideOptions = {
              items: 10, autoplay: true, loop: true, dots: false,
   responsive: {
  0: {
    items: 1
  },

  600: {
    items: 3
  },
  960: {
    items: 5
  },
  1200: {
    items: 6
  },
  1300: {
    items: 10
  }
},
     };
           CarouselOptions = {
         items: 1, autoplay: true, dots: false,
         };
            refreshSlider(){
              console.log(this.owlElement);
            this.owlElement.refresh();
                }
              }
```